# Visemes analogue for phoneme pangram?

Tags: english, phonemes

There are several famous short texts which covers most of the English phonemes.

For example *"With tenure, Suzie'd have all the more leisure for yachting, but her publications are no good."* Or *"Are those shy Eurasian footwear, cowboy chaps, or jolly earthmoving headgear"*.

Can anyone suggest me analogue of such small texts for ***visemes***? I.e text which covers most of the usual lip motions during speech.

Please let me know if there are more appropriate stackexchange site for such question.